# GPE uninstallable on luna m5

Tags: eclipse, google-plugin-eclipse

GPE for 4.3 requires eclipse.core.runtime 3.8 or 3.9 so it works on luna M2. At least since M5 it comes with 3.10.

Aany idea or workaround? Some alpha build?

Comment: Well.. eclipse luna (4.4) M3 comes with eclipse.core.runtime 3.10, so M2 is the last one working with GPE 4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're willing to open up the archived copy of the local update site and the jars inside, you can strip out the hard version requirements and the plugin will install just fine.

--

**update**: i stand corrected, while the plugin installs, functionality does not work properly. it appears google decided to use this 'internal' class -  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.SWTFactory - which doesn't appear to exist anymore (or it got moved).

looks like it's kepler only until they cut a new release.

Comment: See topic here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-plugin-eclipse/4YACQROrB2U